# fetch the unique data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables. ProductA and ProductB.

**ProductA**

```
+----+-------+
| ID | SubId |
+----+-------+
| A1 |  112  |
| B1 |  111  |
| C1 |  115  |
| D1 |  117  |
| E1 |  114  |
| F1 |  112  |
+----+-------+
```

**ProductB**

```
+----+-------+
| ID | SubId |
+----+-------+
| A1 |  112  |
| B1 |  111  |
| C1 |  115  |
| G1 |  001  |
| H1 |  002  |
| k1 |  003  |
+----+-------+
```

I want to write a query which retrieves two columns `ID` and `SubId` and displays distinct rows from `ProductA` table which are NOT IN `ProductB`. So for the above tables.

**Expected Result**

```
+----+-------+
| ID | SubId |
+----+-------+
| D1 |  117  |
| E1 |  114  |
| F1 |  112  |
+----+-------+
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: I tried using left outer join and union as well, but unfortunately getting a duplicate result, not the result I wished to get. Please help

Comment: Please show us some request you made

Comment: put that query here what you tried

Answer (score 1):

**Query**

```
select distinct *
from productA
where not exists
(
  select null 
  from productB
  where productA.id = productB.id
  and productA.subid=productB.subid
);
```

[Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae620/2)

Comment: @user3127368 : If this solved your problem, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select * from ProductA where not EXISTS(select * from productb)
```

Comment: its returning an empty set :(

Comment: More detail refer this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: That query does not make sense. You should re-write your answer according to the linked mysql manual. The sub-query should have a correlation with main query...

Answer (score 0):

### Update

24 revisions later!  How do you like me NOW!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/954792/24

---

```
SELECT
    foo.pid, 
    foo.sid from (
        SELECT 
            PA.`ID` as pid, 
            PA.`SubId` as sid 
        FROM 
            `ProductA` as PA
        LEFT JOIN 
            `ProductB` as PB
        ON 
            PA.`ID` = PB.`ID`
        WHERE 
            PB.`ID` is NULL

        UNION

        SELECT 
            P2A.`ID` as ppid, 
            P2A.`SubId` as ssid 
        FROM 
            `ProductA` as P2A
        RIGHT JOIN 
            `ProductB` as P2B
        ON 
            P2A.`ID` = P2B.`ID`
        WHERE 
            P2B.`ID` is NULL
   ) as foo
```

[image]

Here is a good link that explains joins...

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Though the query shows the desired result, but it containsall the feilds of ProductB table having a value "NULL"

Comment: updated answer, how does that work.   If not, I'll put in SQL fiddle and make sure it works.  :)

Comment: This answer doesn't retrieve the result what OP needs. This will return the rows which are common for both tables.

Comment: Oh Jeez, OK, I'm putting it in a fiddle, stand by ....   (even I get confused on joins still after 10+ years haha)

Comment: @user3127368 Updated answer.  Took forever but I got it.  :)  Please click checkmark to left of my answer to indicate it works.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 : [dude check this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9db23/1). I just added a new row to the table `productB` with `E1,116`. It is obviously different from the row `E1,114` in productA. But `E1,114` is not showing in the result.

Comment: So you want it to be the same on both ID and SubID?  I thought it was just comparing the ID only

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT <select_list>
FROM TableA A
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B
ON A.Key==B.Key
WHERE A.Key is NULL OR B.Key IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from productA a 
left outer join productB b 
on a.ID = b.ID 
and a.subid=b.subid 
where b.subid is null 
and b.id is null;
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You should try following,

```
Select * from ProductA A
  Left Join ProductB B on A.ID = B.Id
Where B.Id is null or B.SubId is null
```

it will give you desire result.